# lost $this->Auth->user('id') when move to host cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

When I used to test `$this->Auth->user('id')` locally, it works well
and the file `/app/Config/core` has this configuration for Session

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake'
    ));
```

Now it is hosted on my server, I was noticed that I needed to change that file,
so it looks like

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php'
    ));
```

But doing this way, I lost `$this->Auth->user('id')`, the other fields I can find.

Answer (score 0):

How did you login the user?

Did you use `$this->Auth->login($this->data);` ?

If so, the user will be logged in with the data in `$this->data` and this data will be saved in the session. Try `debug($this->Auth->user());` You probably will only see the username (and maybe the password).

To retrieve all the User data on login you need to login without passing data to the AuthComponent.

`$this->Auth->login();` will do the magic for you, it will retrieve the user (including the contains) from the database and store this data in the session.

`$this->Auth->login();` will only work when $this->data is filled with the right credentials.

Comment: Thank to answer me. Actually I realized that there is no $this->Auth->user('id') when a user is created. Just when this user logged at the second time appears the var Auth->user('id'). I thought I could have Auth->user('id') creating a user.